# Cache (or otherwise speed up) /admin/users

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, users, performance

When I load /admin/users on SO, I generally get a muffin or something while waiting:

[image]

Those first two XHR requests (to load the all-time users-with-flagged-posts list and the 30 day one, respectively) take a combined 15-ish seconds, dwarfing all the other requests. Because of how the page is organized, I have to wait for the server to render both users-with-flags lists before anything else.

I have never once used the users-with-flags list. When I go to /admin/users, it's *always* to get information about recent messages, annotations, etc. I don't want to have to wait fifteen seconds to get that information.

Those lists change at a snail's pace. Can they be aggressively cached, or perhaps relegated to their own item in /admin/links?

Comment: I dunno... I wouldn't want to deprive you of your daily muffin.

Comment: @AdamLear Don't you know that muffins are evil!?! Undo is slowly killing themself while waiting for this page to load.

Comment: For reference, on [a much smaller site](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) I am seeing 150 ms and 125 ms for those two flagged-post requests. Very noticeable, though not nearly long enough to get a muffin... `[feature-request]` let me eat my muffin :(